# Mathematical operations on ng init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I am trying to do mathematical operations of ng init

```
    <div "dt in data">
     <input type="text" ng-model="dt.in" ng-init="'aaa' + $index + 1">
    </div>
```

Out put in the format of aaa1

But it does not work.

Comment: Did you try this `ng-init="'aaa'" + $index + "1"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) states,

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

This is not what you're doing. What ngInit actually does is to *init* a variable that will be available inside the scope of a ngRepeat. You are not even creating a variable (I mean, putting something like `myVar = someValue`), you are just performing a calculation.

So, I think you should abandon ngInit and instead create a function in your $scope, like:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(index) {
  return 'aaa' + (index + 1);
}
```

And use it like:

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="myFunc($index)">
```

Edit:
I'm not actually sure that the `ng-bind` is exactly what you want, specially considering that you are using it with a `<input>`. I've just used `ng-bind` as an example, you should use whatever you consider more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see calculated value in textbox you need to change to

```
ng-init="dt.in='aaa' + $index + 1"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [

    { in : 1
    }, { in : 2
    }
  ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="dt in data">
      <input type="text" ng-model="dt.in" ng-init="dt.in='aaa' + $index + 1">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```